# How to detect if bootloader is unlocked when fastboot doesn't work?

Tags: bootloader, fastboot

I have this tablet that runs on RK3168 (Rockchip) SoC.  The problem is that fastboot doesn't recognize the device, but after so much toil, I managed to find Finless' flashing tool and flashed CM Recovery image unto the device.  The flashing worked because when I rebooted to recovery mode, it showed CM recovery screen instead of the stock recovery screen.

The flashing tool is a windows GUI.  It doesn't have an unlock bootloader function.  But since I was able to flash the recovery image successfully, my question is, does this mean that my device bootloader is already unlocked?

---

**Edit: (more details)**
Using Finless' flashing tool, I backed up all the NAND partitions and named them accordingly, e.g. backup.img, kernel.img, etc.  Then I reflashed them all back into the device but reflashed a different recovery.img.  I reflashed a generic CM that I got from this site instead: http://androtab.info/clockworkmod/rockchip/

I did all this with the assumption that the flashing tool actually works.  After all, I used it to make the backup as it was the only tool that detected the device in fastboot mode because fastboot just doesn't detect it.  (It could be that the bootloader interface driver doesn't work properly for fastboot on Win x64, but I don't have the luxury of setting up a 32-bit OS.)

When I rebooted the device, everything was fine.  Rebooted into recovery mode and CM recovery screen showed up.

I'm still new to all this android flashing stuff, I don't really know what an unlocked bootloader means, and I just read from other guides that in order to flash a custom recovery, I need an unlocked bootloader first.  So I'm presuming that if I was able to flash images, that my bootloader is already unlocked?  But I'm not sure, so that's why I'm asking (albeit a very naive question...)

Comment: Unfortunately no, the bootloader is a separate entity that will need to be unlocked on it's own. Flashing a custom recovery doesn't automatically unlock it. What is the model of the tablet?

Comment: It's a Starmobile Engage7+ tablet.  It's one of those cheap >$100 tablets.  The problem with these devices is that there's hardly any "official" technical support.  Took me days to get adb to detect the device, and I just gave up on fastboot.

Comment: I gotcha.  I can't find any information in the modding community for that tablet.  I think you're out of luck with unlocking the bootloader.  Towelroot should work for rooting, and other than that, I think you're stuck on the stock ROM.

Comment: But I'm wondering, if I was able to flash NAND partitions while the device was in fastboot mode, not just the recovery partition, doesn't that mean the bootloader's already unlocked?  Edited question to add details.

Comment: Close.  The bootloader runs before the OS is loaded and makes sure that the installed system is "approved."  So, for example, on Samsung devices, the bootloader checks to make sure the system is written by Samsung.  (Almost) every Android device has access to fastboot to help recover the device in case of damage to the OS.  By flashing the stock backups, the bootloader still sees the OS as the original factory OS (which, well, it is).  Does that make sense?  My apologies if I'm talking confusingly!

Comment: I see what you mean.  So it doesn't necessarily mean the bootloader's unlocked.  It could just be that the bootloader allowed a CM recovery to run but it's still unlocked.  Anyhow, I'll keep on reading and searching for other means to figure out how to detect bootloader lock status without using fastboot.  Or maybe even write some script and run from within the device if it needs that stretch.  I hope not!

Comment: Correct!  The recovery is separate from the bootloader.  For example, on my Samsung Galaxy S4, I had custom ROMs and recoveries, but by bootloader was locked (I was still technically running the original Samsung kernel).  I did some looking around and can't find any surefire way of detecting lock status... I'll keep researching and report back if I find anything!

Comment: Give Koush's Universal ADB Driver a try.  It's worth a shot.  https://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver  Then from fastboot you can run `fastboot oem unlock` and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded Koush's universal driver and tried every bootloader interface entry in the list, but fastboot still doesn't work. It just stops at the <waiting for device> message. =(

Comment: Sounds like you'd need Starmobile's drivers. :/

Comment: Hehe, I don't expect anything from Starmobile. But the flashing tool I'm using works, so I'm not worried. I can always reflash the stock images if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Gosh, I almost bricked my device. I got curious and used the images I extracted from the backup.img partition, but those images don't work at all! So I re-flashed using the original boot/kernel/misc images I made earlier, and it's working again! Rockchip definitely has its own flash tool in place of fastboot.